# Примитивное вычисление зависимостей между Linux-пакетами

Tags: linux, prolog, swi-prolog

Подскажите как реализовать вывод зависимостей между пакетами, выводя их в необходимом порядке сборки с учетом зависимостей: сначала пакет который ни от чего не зависит, затем пакет, которые его требует для сборки.

ЗЫ: посматриваю на использование Prolog для замены OpenWrt 8-)

```
pack(gcc).
pack(binutils).
pack(gmp).
pack(mpfr).
pack(mpc).
pack(isl).
pack(kernel).
pack(uclibc).
pack(buildroot).

req(gcc,binutils).
req(gcc,gmp).
req(gcc,mpfr).
req(gcc,mpc).
req(mpfr,gmp).
req(mpc,gmp).
opt(gcc,isl).

build(X) :- pack(X), req(X,Y), build(Y) | pack(X), write("build "),writeln(X).
```

Comment: про замену OpenWrt/Buildroot почти не шутка, очень сильно удивляюсь почему еще не заменили Kbuild и autotools на Пролог.

Comment: 1. заменить openwrt с помощью программы prolog вряд ли получится: переписать (затратив на это фиг знает сколько человеко-лет) тысячи программ, из которых состоит openwrt — задача весьма трудоёмкая. 2. скорее всего, вы подразумевали замену программы make. ну так сравните свою «простыню» с [семи-строчным файлом](http://paste.debian.net/1096743/), выполняющим, как я понимаю, ровно то же самое (пример вывода программы make приведён там же). как думаете, что предпочтёт «сферический программист в вакууме»? вопрос риторический.

Comment: 1. достаточно хотя бы подменять CONFIG_ и генерировать скрипты инициализации, про полное переписывание (почти) согласен
2. достаточно посмотреть простыни 3х .configов + Config.in чтобы больше никуда не заглядывать -- make умеет только даты файлов смотреть, и все. Иначе не появлялись бы всякие cmake autotools etc

Comment: 2.1. файлы `.config` и `config.in` вообще никакого отношения к программе *make* не имеют. они обрабатываются программой *conf*, компилируемой из содержимого каталога `scripts/config`. 2.2. язык, интерпретируемый программой *make* — вполне себе [тьюринг-полный](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3480950/4827341). 2.3. программа *cmake* и набор скриптов *autotools* в конечном счёте генерируют скрипты, интерпретируемые этой самой программой *make*. рассматривать их в качестве «замены» данной программы — приблизительно как рассматривать компилятор в качестве «замены» ассемблера.

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой вариант работает, но выводит повторения, что не очень хорошо:

```
:-style_check(-discontiguous).

pack(gcc).      pack(binutils).
pack(gmp).      pack(mpfr).     pack(mpc).          pack(isl).
pack(kernel).   pack(uclibc).   pack(buildroot).

req(gcc,binutils).  req(gcc,gmp).   req(gcc,mpfr).  req(gcc,mpc).   opt(gcc,isl).
req(mpfr,gmp).
req(mpc,gmp).

req(kernel,gcc).
req(uclibc,gcc).    req(uclibc,kernel).
req(buildroot,gcc). req(buildroot,uclibc).

build(X) :- pack(X), req(X,Y), build(Y);
            pack(X), write("build "),writeln(X).
```

Comment: Графы бывают циклическими.